# Global before_filter in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, before-filter

I need to execute a method before certains actions in a rails app and apparently the right way to go is using a before_filter.

The before_filter works fine when a put the filter method in the controller, but I need to use this filter in all the controllers, and I don't think would be right repeat the filter code en each one of them. So, I moved the code to the application controller, but it stopped work.

I don't know if I'm calling it wrongly, I don't know. What is the right way to do this?

PD: I call the filter this way

```
:before_filter => :get_language
```

Comment: It should work in the application controller. If you put in your code, we might be able to help you more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try `before_filter not :before_filter (symbol)`